# Making Asynchronous Calls Using Twisted Inside a Django Project

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, webserver, twisted

I have a Django web server that accepts requests from clients. In addition, I have another server, written with [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/). I wrote a Twisted protocol - its server "half" is running on the server, and I have a very easy to use client protocol as well.

Occasionally the Django server receives requests that need to initiate a request to the Twisted server. This may obviously be a long operation, so it cannot be synchronous. I'm having trouble incorporating a Twisted client inside the Django project to make these requests.

Simplifying the architecture a bit, it looks something like this:
[image]

Initially, I created a global thread instance in the views.py file of my Django project that runs Twisted's reactor loop, and whenever a request was received through the Django server, I'd add it to the reactor asynchronously to be performed by that thread. This worked fine with the `python manage.py runserver` script, however when I ran it on my Apache server I would sometimes get the requests on the Twisted server and sometimes wouldn't.

I'm assuming this is because Apache also runs several threads, each of which tries to create that reactor-thread. Since there may only be one reactor per process, only one thread succeeds while the others fail, therefore only some requests make it through - the ones in the "winning" thread (this is just a theory, I haven't verified it).

I believe my options are:

1. Somehow share my reactor-thread instance among all Apache threads so that there's really just one reactor. Not sure exactly how to do this - everything I find online talks about sharing **data** (through Django's DB), not sharing instances.
2. Run the Twisted client as a separate process on the Django server machine, and send requests from Django with some RPC method (that is not Twisted-based - otherwise I'd be back in square one of running a Twisted client inside Django, which I cannot seem to be able to do...).

Any advice on what is the correct solution / how to implement it? Is there another way I'm not thinking of?

Thank you.

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did Crotchet work for you or you found another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Crochet](https://warehouse.python.org/project/crochet/).

Stack Overflow thinks this answer isn't sufficient to solve your problem, because it isn't enough words.  But check it out; Crochet does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising. Do you know if it's widely used? (i.e. is it well-tested? Can I use it in production?)

Comment: There's 100% test coverage right on the front page I linked to, so I would say "yes". It's written by Itamar, one of the original Twisted developers, so I'd be very comfortable using it in production.